# invulnerability no longer working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

im trying to make a mob that is invulnerable to all, yesterday on the same mc version I had the same command and it summoned a sheep that could only die to someone in creative mode with a diamond sword, this was good. but now it no longer works. here is the command:
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:apples_ArE_Us,NoAI:1,Invulnerability:1}

Answer (score 1):

The nbt tag is `Invulnerable` not `Invulnerability`

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:apples_ArE_Us,NoAI:1,Invulnerable:1}
```